# CPP: Getting type conversion error in JSON

Tags: c++, json

I am trying to push json objects into vector of json data type. But after loading this vector into json response I am getting one error.

I tried below way to push json objects into vector of json data type.

```
std::vector<json_t*>disks;
json_t *disks_obj = json_object();
string key="DISKS";
string src="<disk-id>";
string baseSnapshotID="<snapID>";
json_object_set_new(disks_obj,"source",json_string(src.c_str()));
json_object_set_new(disks_obj,"baseSnapshotID",json_string(baseSnapshotID.c_str()));
disks.push_back(disks_obj);
json_object_set_new(environment_obj,"disks",json_deep_copy(disks));
```

But I am getting error like:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::vector<json_t*>' to 'const json_t*' for argument '1' to 'json_t* json_deep_copy(const json_t*)'
    json_object_set_new(environment_obj,"disks",json_deep_copy(disks));
```

Comment: What json library do you use?

Comment: You might find a c++ library like nlohmann easier to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jansson is a C library and `json_object_set_new()` expects a C array referenced by a pointer `const json_t*`:

```
json_object_set_new(environment_obj,"disks",json_deep_copy(disks.data()));
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
```